# How to measure the time of transferring a file from the server to the client?

Tags: networking

I want to measure the time of transferring a file from the `send` to the `recv` by the PGM/UDP protocol. Actually , I try to use `clock()` function to measure the execution time of both the `send` and `recv` program ,but it seems to be incorrect. What should I do to measure the time of transferring a file ?

Here is the code :

```
clock_t t = clock();
    do 
    {
                    struct timeval tv;
                    size_t len;
        int timeout;


     pgm_error_t *pgm_err = NULL;
        const int status = pgm_recv (rx_sock,
                                     buf,
                                     sizeof(buf),
                                     0,
                                     &len,
                                     &pgm_err);
        switch (status) 
        {
                case PGM_IO_STATUS_NORMAL:
/* receive file */

                    if (len < 30)
                    {
                        strncpy(newFile, buf, len);
                         if (0 == strncmp(newFile, testNewFile, len))
                        {
                                 flag = 1;
                                 continue;
                         }

                        strncpy(endFile, buf, len);
                        if (0 == strncmp(endFile, testEndFile, len))
                        {

                                //g_quit = 1;
                                t = clock() -t;
                                printf("%s takes time: %f\n", fileName, ((float)t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
                                                                continue;
                        }

                    }


                       if (flag == 1)
                       {
                               strncpy(fileName, buf, len);
                            //   puts(fileName);
                               fp = fopen(fileName, "wb");
                               g_assert(fp);
                               flag = 0;

                       }
                      else

                        num_read = fwrite (buf, sizeof(char), len, fp);


                        break;
                case PGM_IO_STATUS_TIMER_PENDING:
                        {
                            socklen_t optlen = sizeof (tv);
                            pgm_getsockopt (rx_sock, IPPROTO_PGM, PGM_TIME_REMAIN, &tv, &optlen);
                        }
                        goto block;
                case PGM_IO_STATUS_RATE_LIMITED:
                        {
                            socklen_t optlen = sizeof (tv);
                            pgm_getsockopt (rx_sock, IPPROTO_PGM, PGM_RATE_REMAIN, &tv, &optlen);
                        }
                case PGM_IO_STATUS_WOULD_BLOCK:
block:
                        timeout = PGM_IO_STATUS_WOULD_BLOCK == status ? -1 : ((tv.tv_sec * 1000) + (tv.tv_usec / 1000));
                        memset (fds, 0, sizeof(fds));
                        fds[0].fd = g_quit_pipe[0];
                        fds[0].events = POLLIN;
                        pgm_poll_info (rx_sock, &fds[1], &n_fds, POLLIN);
                        poll (fds, 1 + n_fds, timeout);

                        break;
                default:
                        if (pgm_err) 
                        {
                                g_warning ("%s", pgm_err->message);
                                pgm_error_free (pgm_err);
                                pgm_err = NULL;
                        }
                        if (PGM_IO_STATUS_ERROR == status)
                              break;


        }
    }while (!g_quit);


    fclose (fp);
    return NULL;
```

Comment: Do you mean calculate? Or measure? It isn't the same thing.

Comment: oh, What I exactly want to do is measure the time.It's my fault.Thanks!

Comment: OK now define 'seems to be incorrect', and show how you're doing it.

Comment: I just use `clock()` function to measure the execution time of the loop of send and recv code.

Comment: It displays that it just takes 3s to receive the file, but the time from beginning to receive the file to displaying  the finishing receiving the file is obviously more than 3s.I add my code to the question.Thanks!

Comment: I use the `time()` function, it is right!And I google the function `clock()`;Function `clock()`  'Returns the processor time consumed by the program' .The file transfer takes more time in the `Buffer`, and it is not included in the `processor time`?

Comment: The *time spent blocking in recv()* isn't counted as processor time.